# How to simulate the outcome in a simple linear regression given X and R-squared?

Tags: regression, r-squared

Suppose that we have a fixed $R^2$ and one predictor $X$, sample size = $n$. How can we simulate an outcome variable that follows a normal distribution with $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ so that in a simple linear regression model regressing $Y$ on $X$, the $R^2$ would be the one given above? Thank you!

Edited on 2018-07-06: 
To be more specific, I'm wondering if an explicit relationship between $R^2$, $X$, and $Y$ can be derived in a simple linear regression?

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
Y = \alpha + \beta \cdot X + \epsilon \\
\bar{Y} = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y] = 
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i] = 
\alpha + \beta \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]\\
R^2 = \frac{\sum_{i} \epsilon_i^2}{\sum (Y - \bar{Y})^2} \\
$$

You know $R^2$ and you can simulate $X$ and $\epsilon$ simply, since you know the distributions.

$$
\sum_i ([\alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i] - [\alpha + \beta \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]])^2 = 
\sum_i (\beta (X_i - \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]) + \epsilon_i)^2 =
\frac{\sum_{i} \epsilon_i^2}{R^2}
$$

This lets you solve for $\beta$, which allows you to simply simulate Y values

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one predictor your R^2 is actually the square of correlation. It's easy to simulate from 2 dimensional normal distribution. In R use package mvtnorm and rmvnorm function.

Comment: There's no assumption made that X is normal. But in any case X is given (see the title) so you don't need to simulate it.